# How to print alt or title field image in custom block programmatically?

Tags: 8, files

I want to print alt or title field image file in custom module Drupal 8. I load file entity `use Drupal\file\Entity\File;` I checked `core/modules/file/src/Entity/File.php`all public function but not get any function which return title or alt text.

```
$graph_data = Paragraph::load($graph['target_id']);
$output .= '<div class="swiper-slide">';
$output .= '<div class="slide-inner">';
foreach ($graph_data->field_slider_image as $item) {
 $title_img =    "Need image title here";
if ($item->entity) {
$slide_uri = $item->entity->getFileUri();
$url = ImageStyle::load('orignal')->buildUrl($slide_uri);
$output .= '<div class="col-md-6"><img src="'.$url.'" class="img-responsive"><h2>'.$title_img.'</h2></div>';  
}
}
```

Please anyone give idea ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the node and then fetch the paragraph targetid . Later you can load paragraph targetid and then get all attributes of the image.

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph; 
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::load($nid);
$paragraph_field = $node->get("field_paragraph")->getValue();
$paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph_field[0]['target_id']);
$image_alt = $paragraph->my_image_field->alt;
$image_title= $paragraph->my_image_field->title;
```

Answer (score 4):

That information isn't stored against the file entity, its on the image field attached to your source entity (e.g. your node)

So you could do something like:

```
$node->my_image_field->alt
$node->my_image_field->title
```

and that would give you the alt/title

Comment: My image field is in paragraph. May I use same as node ?

Comment: Yeah you'd just load the paragraph entity and do the same as above:
$paragraph->->my_image_field->alt nodes/paragraphs and most other things are all just entities